# Laravel, different prices for different users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have already build a laravel site, But there is a requirement to make item price change depending on the user type.

so here how it should go =>

```
if ($user->type = 'special')
```

I have to get `$item->special_price` rather than the `$item->price` from the database.

There are many places that I show the `$item->price`.

My question is depending on the user login can i overwrite all the places which i am using `$item->price` to  `$item->special_price` ?

Comment: price comes from database ?

Comment: yes it is connected to a db

Comment: you can create a method specialPrice and make return like $this->price* something

Comment: there are too many places change, im trying to get it done inside the model ,overwrite price calls with special_price ... something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel allows you to create custom attributes on your models

```
class Item extends Model {
    public function getCurrentPriceAttribute(){
        return auth()->user()->type == 'special'
          ? $this->special_price
          : $this->price
    }
}
```

Here we are using the `auth()` helper to get the current user. We check the user type and if it is special we fetch the `special_price` if the user is not special we return the "normal" `price`.

You can use `$item->currentPrice` to get the price for the current user.

Comment: ok , i can try this out.I was thinking of using something like this but there are lots of places i need to change in order to use this because currently im just  using $this->price all the places. I was trying to find a way to injecting $this->special_price into $this->price in the model so that i dont have to change code in many places

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = auth()->user()->type=='normal'||(other  user types where u need $item->price)?'price':auth()->user()->type.'_price';

$price = $item[$key];
```

Comment: Please, provide context, not just correct code. What's wrong with code provided by question author ? What is your improvement ?